# VBA RANDOM SELECTION BASED ON MAX VALUE

Tags: vba, powerquery, m

Hello being facing an issue with the following :

I need to select a list of product based on max budget,

**Data**
Item 1 : 1 usd
Item 2 : 3 usd
Item 3 : 0.5 usd
Item 4 : 40 usd
Item 5 : 20 usd
Item 6 : 5 usd

Budget = 50 usd

The needed output : different list of product i can get where the sum of price is equal to or less than 50 usd,list can contain 1 products as well.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Language : Vba or M query

Comment: Any code you got so far? This looks like a Knapsack problem, google it.

Comment: @milo5m no code so far,but thank you i did not know about Knapsack problem and it's indeed. now i have the key word to google it.

Answer (score 2):

In powerquery: Create every combination. Price them. Filter amount as needed

function **Combinations**

```
(Items as list) as table =>
//  Bill Szysz 2017, all combinations of items in list, blows up with too many items to process due to large number of combinations
let AddIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.FromList(Items), "Index", 0, 1),
ReverseIndeks = Table.AddIndexColumn(AddIndex, "RevIdx", Table.RowCount(AddIndex), -1),
Lists = Table.AddColumn(ReverseIndeks, "lists", each 
  List.Repeat(
      List.Combine({
           List.Repeat({[Column1]}, Number.Power(2,[RevIdx]-1)),
           List.Repeat(   {null}, Number.Power(2,[RevIdx]-1))
       })
   , Number.Power(2, [Index]))
),
ResultTable = Table.FromColumns(Lists[lists])
in ResultTable
```

**used with code**:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Item", type text}, {"Amount", type number}}),
GetCombos = Combinations(#"Changed Type"[Item]),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(GetCombos, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Value"},  #"Changed Type", {"Item"}, "ct", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded ct" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "ct", {"Amount"}, {"Amount"}),
#"Group"= Table.Group(#"Expanded ct", {"Index"}, {
    {"Concat", each Text.Combine([Value],", "), type text},
    {"Cost", each List.Sum([Amount]), type number}}
),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Group,{"Index"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each [Cost] <= 50)
in #"Filtered Rows"
```

[image]